# How to calculate the conduction losses diodes in each stage

Tags: voltage

how I can calculate the power losses for each step in The voltage multiplier (3 steps). I work in low voltage and  power so some milliwatt losses are important in my system how I can calculate the power losses of the capacitors in each stage [image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. You need to ask a question that can be answered without writing down a year of electrical engineering university. Your question is too broad. You need to describe where you're stuck.

Comment: Simulators are your best friend here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about a halfwave Cockcroft-Walton voltage mulitiplier, you can approximate the output voltage from this equation:

$$ E_{out} = 2nE_{pk} - \frac {I_{load}}{2 \pi fC} (4n^3 + 3n^2 - n) - 2nV_{f}$$

What that does is to compute your output voltage from several parameters:

- \$E_{pk}\$ the peak voltage of the AC input (**not** the peak to peak voltage, but the simple peak voltage.)
- \$I_{load}\$ - the load current.
- \$f\$ - the frequency of the AC input
- \$C\$ - the capacitance of your individual capacitors (in farads.)
- \$n\$ - the number of stages in your multiplier.
- \$V_{f}\$ - the forward voltage of your diodes.

You can estimate the impedance from an \$n\$ stage multiplier with this equation:

$$ Z = \frac {4n^3 + 3n^2 - n}{2 \pi fC}  $$

I've posted the above equations before, and I have some background on them on my [blog.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/diode-capacitors-volts-pt7)

You can't really calculate a "power loss" for each stage.

- The capacitors don't dissipate (much) power - it's reactance and not resistance.
- The diodes will dissipate some power, but again not much.  You normally only draw milliamperes of current from a multiplier.  The product of the current and the forward voltage gives a dissipated power of milliwatts in the diodes.

The biggest problem with a voltage multiplier is the impedance.  As you can see, it goes up quite rapidly with the number of stages.  You can use larger capacitors and/or higher frequencies to make the impedance lower, but it still goes up rapidly.

---

If all you really need is the conduction losses in the diodes, then that is the product of the load current and the forward voltage of each diode.

$$ P = I_{Load} \times V_{forward} \times 2 \times n$$

That will tell you the power dissipated in all the diodes for an n-stage half wave Cockroft-Walton voltage multiplier.

---

Something you should **not** do is to short circuit a voltage multiplier.  At high current levels, the output voltage drops to such an extent that you have just a bunch of diodes in series between the source and the output.  If the source impedance is low enough, it will destroy the diodes.

Comment: what is the effect of the impedance in the voltage multipllier